# Skyve on Wildfly wont restart with StateTransitionException

Tags: wildfly, skyve

On restart of Wildfly I get the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: Persistence directory already locked by this process: C:\bizhub\workspace\content\SKYVE_CACHE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutdown Wildfly if it is running, in the directory named in the exception (in this case C:\bizhub\workspace\content\SKYVE_CACHE) there will be a file called .lock, if this file is removed and wildfly is restarted this should resolve the issue.